# How to get mpi4py processes to finish printing before executing time.sleep()?

Tags: python, mpi4py, ms-mpi

When I run the code below using `mpiexec -n 5 python mpiTest.py`, I expect every process to print its message immediately, then sleep for the specified amount of time. Instead, it executes as if I put the `print` command AFTER the `sleep` command. Why does this happen and how can I get it to behave as expected?

Adding a `MPI.COMM_WORLD.Barrier()` between the `print` and `sleep` commands does NOT help.

I'm using MS-MPI on win10.

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import random
import time

def delayed():
    random.seed()
    sek = random.randint( 1, 5 )
    print( "Delaying for ", sek, " seconds." )
    time.sleep( sek )
    return

delayed()
```

Comment: You probably need to flush your IO buffer.  Try `sys.stdout.flush()` after the `print` call.

Answer (score 10):

Adding `sys.stdout.flush()` after the `print` call did the trick, thanks ever so much! =)